# Why the norm is $>1$ for one projection operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $P: c \to c$ be a projection operator onto $c_0 \subseteq c$. That is, $P$ is a bounded operator such that $P^2=P$ and $\operatorname{Im} P=c_0$. We are asked to show that $\lVert P\rVert > 1$.

My attempt was:
For any $w\in c$ we have that

$$\lVert Pw \rVert= \lVert P^2 w\rVert \leq \lVert P\rVert^2 \lVert w\rVert$$ this implies that $\frac{\lVert Pw \rVert}{\lVert w\rVert}\leq \lVert P\rVert^2$ or equivalently $1\leq \lVert P\rVert$. I do know why the inequality is strict. Hence, the other side we know that for all $w\in c $ then $w=w-P(w)+P(w)$ where $w-P(w)\in \ker P$ and $P(w)\in c_0= \operatorname{Im} P$, so $\lvert c \rvert = \lvert \ker P \rvert + \lvert c_0 \rvert > \lvert c_0\rvert$ where i mean $\lvert c \rvert := \operatorname{dim}c$. I guess that I need to find some particular element in the domain for attach the grater dimension or something like that. I am not sure if $c_0$ are the sequence that converge to $0$ for this reason i did no try other thing with sequences. I will appreciate any hint please.

Best

Comment: If $c_0 =c$, and $P$ is the identity, then the norm is exactly $1$,  so maybe you're supposed to prove $\ge 1$?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: $c_0$ and $c$ are not the same.

Comment: "$c_0 \subseteq c$", so it's not necessarily the case, but it is possible.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: no, not at all. $c$ is the set of convergent sequences, while $c_0$ is the set of sequences that converge to $0$. They are not the same.

Comment: Oh! Those specific $c$ and $c_0$! Okay, my mistake, I didn't read all the way to the end. Question should probably be edited so that is clearly stated as part of the problem, not as a hazarded guess at the end of the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be a projection onto $c_0.$ We will show that $\|P\|\ge 2.$

Let $x_\infty =\lim x_n.$ Observe that $P$ is of the form $$P_vx=x-x_\infty v,\quad\ v\in c,\ v_\infty=1\quad (*)$$ Indeed. let $1{\hskip -2.5 pt}\hbox{l}$ denote the constant sequence with all terms equal $1.$ we have $$\displaylines{Px=P(x-x_\infty 1{\hskip -2.5 pt}\hbox{l})+x_\infty  P1{\hskip -2.5 pt}\hbox{l}\\ =x-x_\infty 1{\hskip -2.5 pt}\hbox{l} +x_\infty P1{\hskip -2.5 pt}\hbox{l}\\ = x-x_\infty (1{\hskip -2.5 pt}\hbox{l}-P1{\hskip -2.5 pt}\hbox{l})}$$ thus $v=1{\hskip -2.5 pt}\hbox{l}-P1{\hskip -2.5 pt}\hbox{l},$ which completes the proof of $(*).$

From now on we are dealing with $P_v$ for a sequence $v$ with $v_\infty =1.$
Let $x^{N}$ denote the sequence with terms $$x^{(N)}_n=\begin{cases} -v_n& 1\le n\le N\\ v_n & n>N\end{cases}$$ Then the limits of this sequence is equal $v_\infty,$ i.e. $x^{(N)}_\infty =v_\infty=1,$ $\|x^{(N)}\|=\|v\|.$ By $(*)$ we obtain
$$[P_v(x^{(N)})]_n = \begin{cases} -2v_n& 1\le n\le N\\ 0 & n>N\end{cases}$$ Thus $$\|P_v(x^{(N)})\|=2\max_{1\le n\le N}|v_n|\underset{N}{\rightarrow}2=2\|x^{(N)}\|$$ Hence $\|P_v\|\ge 2.$

**Remark**

It may occur that the norm $2$ is not attained at any element $x\in c.$ For example let $$v_n=1-{1\over n}$$ Then $$\|P_vx\|=\|x-x_\infty v\| \le 2\|x\| $$ Assume, by contradiction that there is $x\in c $ such that $$\|x-x_\infty v\|=2,\quad \|x\|=1$$ With no loss of generality we may assume $x_\infty >0.$
Then $$2=\|x-x_\infty v\|\le \|x\|+x_\infty\le 2$$ Hence $x_\infty =1$ and $$\|x-v\|=2$$ As $\lim(x_n-v_n)=0$ there is $n$ such that $|x_n-v_n|=2.$ This gives a contradiction because $|x_n|\le 1$ and $0<v_n<1.$

Comment: Very nice. You can write it a bit more conceptually, without coordinates, if you define $v=P1$, and $x_n=v-2Q_nv$, where $Q_n$ is the projection onto the first $n$ coordinates. Since $1-2Q_n$ is a unitary it is isometric, which gives you $\|x_n\|=\|v\|=1$. And $Px_n=-2Q_nv$, so $\|Px_n\|=2\|Q_nv\|$. Since $v\in c_0$, taking $n$ big enough (no need for limits) gives you $\|Px_n\|=2$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thanks. Wonderful simplification ! I will keep my answer the way it stands, along with your comment below.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I think the limit is necessary, as the operator norm may be not attained. See the remark at the end of my answer. Or I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. The mistake in what I wrote is that $v=1-P1$ and not just $P1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** we always have $\|P\|\geq2$. See Ryszard's great answer.

*(my older answer below)*

---

Let $y=P1$.  We consider two cases:

- If $\|y\|>1$, then $\|P1\|=\|y\|>1=\|1\|$, and we get $\|P\|>1$.
- If $\|y\|\leq1$, fix $k$ such that $|1-y_k|>\frac12$ (such $k$ exists because $y\in c_0$). Let $(1-y_k)=|1-y_k|\,e^{i\theta}$ be the polar decomposition. Let
  $$
  x=-\frac14\,(1-y)+e^{i\theta}\,e_k. 
  $$
  We have $Px=e^{i\theta}\,e_k$, so $\|Px\|=1$. And
  $$
  \|x\|=\max\big\{\max\{\frac14|1-y_j|:\ j\ne k\},\big|-\frac14\,|1-y_k|+1\big|\,\big\}.
  $$
  Since $\|y\|\leq1$, we have $\frac14\,|1-y_j|\leq\frac24=\frac12$. And
  $$
  \big|-\frac14\,|1-y_k|+1\big|=1-\frac14\,|1-y_k|<1-\frac18.
  $$
  Then
  $$
  \|Px\|=1>1-\frac18>\|x\|,
  $$
  and hence $\|P\|>1$.

Comment: Hi Martin. I just got up. The norm is at least $2$ if I am not mistaken in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I just read your answer and commented on it. Very very nice.

Comment: thank you Martin and Ryszard